# How to add picture to database with laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-7

I am creating `Laravel 7` project and I want to add/browse images into/from `MySQL` database. 
The images column names are `icon_lg` and `icon_sm`

This is my create function in the `Controller` I tried it in two ways as I saw in some tutorials:

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $object = $this->objectModel::create([
                    'name' => $request->name,
                    'icon_sm' => $request->icon_sm
        ]);
        if($request->hasFile('icon_lg')) {
                $images = explode(',', $request->hasFile('icon_lg'));
                foreach($images as $image)
                    $filename = rand().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $filePath = public_path("images");
                    $image->move($filePath, $filename);
                    return Image::create([
                      'icon_lg' => $filename,
                      //'item_id' => $created->id,
                    ]);
            }

        if ($request->save == 'browse')
            return redirect()->route("{$this->objectName}");
        elseif ($request->save == 'edit')
            return redirect()->route("{$this->objectName}.edit", ['id' => $object]);
        elseif ($request->save == 'add')
            return redirect()->route("{$this->objectName}.add");
        else
            return redirect($request->previous_url);
    }
```

It does nothing with `icon_lg` it inserts null value to it.
And it deals with `icon_sm` as String.

[image: This is the database table.]

Answer (score 0):

i think you must set the hasfile validation inside foreach loop like

```
            $images = explode(',', $request->hasFile('icon_lg'));
            foreach($images as $image)
                if($request->hasFile('icon_lg')) {
                  $filename = rand().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                  $filePath = public_path("images");
                  $image->move($filePath, $filename);
                  return Image::create([
                    'icon_lg' => $filename,
                    //'item_id' => $created->id,
                  ]);
                }
```

just test it without validation first
it should work